# List Directories in Decending Order

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list

I am trying to list directories in decending order by directory name.  They are still being listed in accending order.  Can someone please help me fix the below code as I can't seem to get it working correctly.  I am not getting an error with the below code, its showing the list in accending order by name.

```
        Dim oDirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Test/" & Session("Test")) & sSubDir)
        Dim oDirs As DirectoryInfo() = oDirInfo.GetDirectories()
        For Each oDir As DirectoryInfo In oDirs
            oDir.GetDirectories().OrderByDescending(Function(eachDir) eachDir.Name).FirstOrDefault()
            Try
                Response.Write((((("<TR><TD class=""tdDir""><A href=""" & lsScriptName & "?path=" & lsWebPath) + oDir.Name & "&title=" & lsTitle & "&link=" & lsLink & """>") + oDir.Name & "</A></TD><TD class=""tdDir"">Dir</TD><TD class=""tdDir"" align=""right"">") + oDir.LastWriteTime & "</TD><TD class=""tdDir"" align=""right"">") & " Folder</TD></TR>")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(("<TR><TD class=""tdDir"">" + oDir.Name & " (Error Accessing Directory)</TD><TD class=""tdDir"">Dir</TD><TD class=""tdDir"" align=""right"">") + oDir.LastWriteTime & "</TD><TD class=""tdDir"" align=""right"">? files</TD></TR>")
            End Try
        Next
```

Comment: What happens if you do this? oDir.GetDirectories().OrderByAscending - I'm just curious... :)

Comment: your oDir.GetDirectories().OrderByDescending() is within your for each loop, so it's not going to work and it's going to resort on each iteration.  You should be able to move that statement above the For Each for it to work.

Comment: I have tried it above the for each loop, but I don't really know how to word it correctly.  It keeps complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this above your For Each:

```
Array.Reverse(oDirs)
```

Since GetDirectories() returns the directories in ascending alpha order, that's all you have to do.

Comment: It says "value of the type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' cannot be converted to 'system.array'

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, object prefixes. You know those are no longer encouraged?

```
Dim ParentDir As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Test/" & Session("Test")) & sSubDir)
For Each oDir As DirectoryInfo In ParentDir.GetDirectories().OrderByDescending(Function(eachDir) eachDir.Name)
    Try
        Response.Write((((("<TR><TD class=""tdDir""><A href=""" & lsScriptName & "?path=" & lsWebPath) + oDir.Name & "&title=" & lsTitle & "&link=" & lsLink & """>") + oDir.Name & "</A></TD><TD class=""tdDir"">Dir</TD><TD class=""tdDir"" align=""right"">") + oDir.LastWriteTime & "</TD><TD class=""tdDir"" align=""right"">") & " Folder</TD></TR>")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(("<TR><TD class=""tdDir"">" + oDir.Name & " (Error Accessing Directory)</TD><TD class=""tdDir"">Dir</TD><TD class=""tdDir"" align=""right"">") + oDir.LastWriteTime & "</TD><TD class=""tdDir"" align=""right"">? files</TD></TR>")
    End Try
Next
```